# Vendor app in android AOSP build tree

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android.mk, android-8.1-oreo

In Android 8.1 we can build and install the application in the vendor partition in the AOSP build tree.
by using `LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_VENDOR_APPS)`
After the installation, I found that the .apk file resides in the following path vendor/app/SampleApp/SampleApp.apk and data files are available in the data/data/.

And lib(pre-build .so libs) folder pointing to the vendor/app/SampleApp/SampleApp/libs but there is no folder like that.

I have extracted the application and found the lib files are available in .apk file.

What is the difference between the vendor application build and system build?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Yes, Please find the answer from the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983553/vendor-application-build-aosp